# Ajax Javascript method cannot be called

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made this method to load JavaScript functions dynamically. It does include the `.js` file, but when I call a method, the method says that it is undefined. The following two `.js` files are `ajax_object.js` and `user_manager.js`.

The alert outside the function is read and works, but the alert inside does not.

```
enter code here
//ajax_object.js
//Load a javascript library
 function loadJavascript( src, url ){

XMLHttpRequestObject=getXmlHttpRequestObject();

if( XMLHttpRequestObject){

    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 ){


            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200 || XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 304) {
                includeJavaScript( src, url, XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText );
            }
        }
    }

}

XMLHttpRequestObject.open('GET', url, true);
XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);

  }//end LoadJavaScript

 //Add Library to header
function includeJavaScript(src, fileUrl, xmlObject)  { 
if ( ( xmlObject != null ) && ( !document.getElementById( src ) ) ){ 
    var documentHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
    var includeScript = document.createElement( "script" );
    includeScript.language = "javascript";
    includeScript.type = "text/javascript";
    //includeScript.id = src;
    includeScript.src=fileUrl.concat(src);
    includeScript.defer = true;
    includeScript.text = xmlObject;
    documentHead.appendChild( includeScript );
} 
  } 

//user_manager.js
 //First alert is read
 alert("Outside User Manager");
  function selectUserManagerModuleType(){
XMLHttpRequestObject=getXmlHttpRequestObject();
//This doesn't work
    //throws selectUserManagerModuleType undefined
alert("Inside The User Manager");



    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm, e.g. using the `net` tab in Firebug, that the script(s) really get loaded?

Comment: Using net, I do get this:

GET user_manager.js   304 Modified

Firebug also shows this:
<script id="user_manager.js" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/user_manager.js" defer="">

In the Response tab, the script does show up:
alert("Outside User Manager");
function selectUserManagerModuleType(){
 XMLHttpRequestObject=getXmlHttpRequestObject();
 //This doesn't work
 alert("Inside The User Manager");
 
}

And if it makes any difference, the script is being called by PHP after it is loaded:

echo "<script language=\"javascript\">selectUserManagerModuleType();</script>";

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you assigned the function to a variable and invoked it that way...

Answer (score 0):

The problem came to an asychnrounous vs sychronous. The solution became very simple with JQuery.

```
function loadJavascript( src, url ){

    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    $.getScript(url.concat(src));
    $.ajaxSetup({async: true});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit odd, you are both giving the script block an src and a body, seemingly containing the same script.

I see two ways of doing this, either you simply add a script block to the header including an src, no ajax call needed for this (I have never seen this done before, so no guarantees as to what will happen). Or you load the script using an ajax call and eval the content returned, you got to beware about scope, otherwise you might end up having the downloaded script declaring stuff in the scope of the function that does the eval, but otherwise it is pice of cake.

If you replace the includeJavaScript call with:

```
eval("with(window){"+XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText+"}")
```

I don't see why it shouldn't work.